# How can I make a query string tamper-proof?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I need to use query strings in a URL, but need to ensure that they haven't been tampered with.  [I found a solution which almost works](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TamperProofQueryString.aspx), but the encoded strings get mangled by a service my app needs to use.  Can anyone think of a different solution?

EDIT: The solution I mention doesn't work for me because the Base64 encoded query string it produces contains "+".  The service I pass this query string to doesn't properly handle "+", and I can't even URL encode it to "%2B".  I can substitute "_" for it, I suppose.  However, I was wondering if there was a different solution entirely.

EDIT 2: To be more clear, the solution I reference works, but I was wondering about alternative solutions.

Comment: You probably need to be a little more specific about what doesn't work about your linked solution.  How does the result "get mangled"?

Comment: The link you gave only Base64 - encodes the URL. This is not tamper proof.

Comment: @Mathias: Yes, the solution I link to doesn't encrypt the query string.  However, that's separate from tamperproofing.

Answer (score 4):

you can encrypt your querystring value and then pass it and where you want to use, simply decrypt it.
Also check these articles...
[how-to-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net](http://nayyeri.net/how-to-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The second link is the same one I reference in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Basically a duplicate of:
[Security with QueryString values in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245569/security-with-querystring-values-in-asp-net-mvc)

Bottom line - never trust input from the user especially over the web, always assume a user can and will tamper with the inputs.

Comment: Exactly -- that's why I want to tamperproof my query string.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute and  pass a hash of your parameters along with your querystring. On your landing page, compute the hash again and compare it with the query string hash, if both are not same it means the URL is tampered.

You can make functions inside a utility class like

```
const string secretKey = "%%YoUrSeCrEtKeY##";

     public static string CreateTamperProofUrl(string pageUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CreateDigest(pageUrl.Trim()));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string CreateDigest(string pageUrl)
    {
        string urlToEncode = secretKey + pageUrl + secretKey;
        var hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] hashedDataBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(urlToEncode));
        string signatureData = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);

        return signatureData;
    }

    public static bool IsValidDigest(string pageUrl, string receivedDigest)
    {
        if (receivedDigest == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string expectedDigest = CreateDigest(pageUrl);
        if (string.Compare(receivedDigest, expectedDigest) != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

On your landing page just check like this

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Digest"] != null)
            {
                // compare the digest
                string id = Request.QueryString["fid"];
                string digest = Request.QueryString["Digest"];

                if (Utility.IsValidDigest(id, digest))
                {
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Valid digest received";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Url is tampered!";
                }

            }
   }
```

Comment: MD5CryptoServiceProvider is at all good for encryption. i heard it is weak encryption algorithm.