# Hide url routing parameters in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a method for specifically hiding the routing parameters in ASP.NET MVC from the users. Specifically, I'd like a link

http://sitename.com/Do?title = 2
to simply become
http://sitename.com/Do

but internally pass the titleId to my controller.

Is that do able?

Thanks

Update: yes, there are buttons on my webpage that currently have such as their href, but I'd rather hide all the parameters so users dont go to other parts of the page directly by trying differnt parameters. @Moshe, no its not a from submit or post else I'd have used a strongly typed view. Thanks

Comment: will users at one point request this page?

Comment: I'll add to the comment made by Emmanuel - is "Do" an action invoked using a form submit? specifically using the POST method?

Comment: Could you expound upon "hide"? Do you not want it in the URL, or do you not want it transmitted over the wire at all?

Comment: @Aaron, I dont want the parameters in the URL to be visible to the users but it needs to be transmitted to my controller..hence the hiding the parameters from the user

Comment: One option is to encode/decode the querystring in some way, but do I understand correctly that you are after a clean looking URL? In that case an option is to transmit your request and update the page asynchronously.

Comment: It's also possible to stuff additional values into a cookie, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple numeric values that have to be passed back and forth to a view you can write two private methods in your controller:

```
private int Obscure(int source) {
    return (source*source) * 3; //or something clever you come up with
}

private int DeObscure(int obscuredValue) {
    return (int)Math.Sqrt(obscuredValue / 3); //inverse the Obscure method
}
```

You can use these to obscure values before you pass them to a view, and de-obscure them after you get them posted back. Mind you, this is really not a good way to implement security, as is explained in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245569/security-with-querystring-values-in-asp-net-mvc).

Another option is to create an Obscure/DeObscure procedure that takes in the entire querystring and somehow mangles that back and forth. This would required writing a custom ViewEngine though. Sounds interesting...

Answer (score 2):

As long as your parameters are on the client, they are never 'hidden' unless you encrypt them. You could store the parameter in a hidden field and set the action method to post, then the value is not visible in the URL. But a user with a little bit of knowlegde about web could still manipulate the hidden field (unless you encrypt the value in some way).

EDIT: If it has to be save you have to check the user's credentials on the server. Otherwise you can obscure the data like in the other sample or you can use encryption, e.g. with ProtectData.Protect(...).

Comment: OK. I will see how i can encrypt the values. any idea how i can encrypt the values?

Comment: If you just want to keep nosy users away, you could encode (or obscure) your data. But this is not very safe as it can easily be guessed. An easy way to encrypt would be ProtectedData.Protect(..), but you have to decrypt the values on the same machine (not suitable for farms).