# How to prevent user tampering of query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just started reading the book Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 and can't seem to find the answer to my question in the book or online.

If say I have a url like so www.something.com/AccountOptions?UserId=1
what is to prevent a user from simply changing the number and altering options from other users? Is there a way to pass data without passing it in the query string and hence hiding it and preventing tampering?

***EDIT*** check the last comment for a redirect to a question that has already been answered.

Comment: no, it is impossible, don't rely on any data from user

Comment: Your only defense against query string hacking is strong validation and variable escaping.

Comment: You should always have server side validation regardless of the clientside

Comment: that is what they are saying in this book. Never trust your users and to HTTP Encode all input that isnt taken in with helper methods. @Mike Purcell do you know of any good reads when it comes to validating that users only access areas they are allowed to? I would image maybe make use of simple membership on user specific views to check and make sure the logged in user has the same id as the query string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.net implementations, but with PHP there are a variety of frameworks which provide various ways of controlling access. In a recent project I ended up create a basic groups/roles configuration where a user was assigned to a group and the group to a role. Then when user logs in, their credentials are pulled from database, and compared with various locations throughout the site. I can't recommend any specific readings (not asp.net proficient), but you could take a look at Zend or Symfony, frameworks, as the security principles are generally universal.

Comment: This is a duplicate question of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245569/security-with-querystring-values-in-asp-net-mvc?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont pass userId back.
Inside your action method, call

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

to get your `userId` and use this Id for your authorization logic